# Adding half month in oracle pl/sql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I get a `period` from another select then I have to add half month to that date but it's not working . It's not giving me an error but the month is not being added when I try to change date based on `newdate` and `delai` (which is declared as FLOAT)

```
d_date = ADD_MONTHS( newdate ,  delai);
```

When `period` = 0.5 running  `dbms_output.put_line(delai);` returns: `,5`

thank you

Comment: "half a month" is ill-defined.  You have to define what you mean.

Comment: it's literally half a month 0,5 in the database we have 0,25 ,  0,5 , 1 , 6 , 12

Comment: "literally half a month" doesn't really clarify things. What is half of January? 14 days? 15 days? 16 days? What about February - 14 days? What about in a leap year?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`add_months()` takes an integer for its second argument. It's for adding whole months to the passed date. Even that is controversial (consider the output of `add_months(date '2019-02-28', 1)` against `add_months(date '2020-02-28', 1)` ).

If we pass a float to `add_months()` it just rounds down rather than hurling an exception. (Also, controversial, perhaps.) Thus passing `0.5` means it just returns the input date unchanged.

So, what do you mean by "half a month"? It's not a standard unit of time, as it depends on what month we are discussing.

If you mean two weeks, use that:

```
d_date := new_date + interval '14' day; -- interval doesn't support WEEK in Oracle
```

> in the database we can add by a week (0.25), 2 weeks ( 0.5 ) , a month , or a year (12 ) and so on

You need to handle it programmatically. Declare an variable to hold an interval

```
i interval day to second;
```

Then your code should look something like this:

```
if period < 1 then
    if period  = 0.25 then 
       i := interval '7' day; 
    elsif period  = 0.5 then 
       i := interval '14' day; 
    elsif period  = 0.75 then 
       i := interval '21' day; 
    end if;
    d_date := new_date + i;
else
    d_date := add_months(new_date, period);
end;
```

Comment: in the database we can add by a week (0.25),  2 weeks ( 0.5 ) , a month , or  a year (12  ) and so on ..   so basically they use months to increment the date so i cannot simply use 14

Answer (score 1):

If you want 'half a month' to mean half the number of days in that month then you could calculate that:

```
declare
  d_date date;
  delai float := 0.5;
  new_date date := date '2019-01-01';
begin
  d_date := new_date + floor(delai * extract(day from last_day(new_date)));
  dbms_output.put_line(d_date);
end;
/

2019-01-16


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

With `new_date` set to 2019-02-01 instead it gives 2019-02-15.

The `last_day()` function gives you the date on last day of that month, as you might guess; then `extract(day from ...)` gives you just the day number, i.e 28, 29, 30 or 31. That's then multiplied by half, and the `floor()` stops any fractional days being added (which would affect the time portion).

Depending on your actual requirements you might want to subtract a day, or use `ceil()` instead of `floor()`, or something else, but I think this is close to what you described.

The same approach will work whether `delai` is 0.5 or 0.25; but for integer values you would probably then need to switch back to `add_months()`. Non-integer values (1.25?) would be headache even then, if they can occur...